# Account.Name field is replaced by Account.Id when doing a System.Debug()

Tags: soql, developer-console

Good morning,

I am a bit puzzled as to why the following query:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Account.Name,CloseDate,Amount FROM Opportunity
```

Shows me the right results when executing the query from the Developer Console, but  when doing a `System.Debug()` it replaces `Account.Name` by `AccountId`

```
Opportunity:{Id=0068d000003D2JeAAK, Name=Edge Emergency Generator, AccountId=0018d000004LcCBAA0, CloseDate=2019-09-30 00:00:00, Amount=75000.00}
```

Anybody knows why is this and how could I make sure that Account.Name gets printed????

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the query, but a limitation of System.debug. It does not output parent or child relationships, and will only show a limited number of fields on the object in question. If you want to see the entire object, you'll have to serialize it:

```
System.debug(
  JSON.serializePretty(
    [SELECT Name, Account.Name, CloseDate, Amount
     FROM Opportunity]
  )
);
```

System.debug is not meant to be used to output entire objects, in the general sense, so you cannot always rely on it to show the full output unless you serialize an object.

Comment: You taught me something important today!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Sergi You're welcome!